# How to show an interval of pages via page viewer

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am currently making a small book like game for educational purposes and I am using page viewer to put information from my Strings.xml on each page. This is a rather small book so I am doing it this way. I have all the pages displayed and you can swipe through without any issues. My problem starts when I just want to display a certain interval of pages. There are three lessons in the game. In lesson one there are 2 pages (1-2), lesson two there are (3-9), and lesson three (10-15). There are 15 pages total of information.

Is there a way to have page viewer only display a certain interval of pages?

I have the user selecting a button and this sends an intent with what lesson was picked to another class called BookActivity. From there I get the intent to figure out which lesson was clicked and want to display certain pages based on that. Here is the bookActivity class.

```
    public class BookActivity extends Activity
{
    private String getLessonName;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        // getting object's properties from LoginActivity class.

        getLessonName = intent.getStringExtra("nameOfLesson");
        MyPageAdapter adapter = new MyPageAdapter();
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);

       // Button addBasicQuestionsForFirstLesson = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addBasicQuestionsButton);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        if(getLessonName.equals("one"))
        {
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        if(myPager.getCurrentItem() == 1)
        {
            myPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        }
        }
        else if(getLessonName.equals("two"))
        {
            myPager.setCurrentItem(2);
            if(myPager.getCurrentItem() == 8)
            {
                myPager.setCurrentItem(8);
            }
        }
        else if(getLessonName.equals("three"))
        {
            myPager.setCurrentItem(9);
            if(myPager.getCurrentItem()==14)
            {
                myPager.setCurrentItem(14);
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Thank you very much for looking at this for me. I would really appreciate it if anyone knew how to do something like this. I don't want to make multiple activities for separate pages if this there is a way to do this better....

```
 class MyPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter
```

{

```
public int getCount()
{
    return 15;
}

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position)
{

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int resId = 0;
    switch (position)
    {
    case 0:

        resId = R.layout.activity_page_one;

        break;
    case 1:
        // second page with button to add questions!
        resId = R.layout.activity_page_two;

        View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.linearbasic);
        Button addButton = (Button) layout
                .findViewById(R.id.addBasicQuestionsButton);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.d("clicked", "clclcl");
                LessonActivity.
                importQuestions("lessononebasicquestions");
                // LessonActivity.clicked = true;
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yay",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        return view;

        // break;
    case 2:

        resId = R.layout.activity_page_three;

        break;
    case 3:
        resId = R.layout.activity_page_four;
        break;
    case 4:
        resId = R.layout.activity_page_five;
        break;
    case 5:
        resId = R.layout.activity_page_six;
        break;
    case 6:
        resId = R.layout.activity_page_seven;
        break;
    case 7:
        resId = R.layout.activity_page_eight;
        break;
    case 8:
        resId = R.layout.activity_page_nine;

        View view2 = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        LinearLayout layout2 = (LinearLayout) view2
                .findViewById(R.id.linearlife);
        Button lifeCycleButton = (Button) layout2
                .findViewById(R.id.addLifeCycleButton);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view2, 0);

        lifeCycleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.d("clicked", "clclcl");
                LessonActivity
                .importQuestions("lessontwolifecyclequestions");
                // LessonActivity.clicked = true;
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yay",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        return view2;

    case 9:
        resId = R.layout.activity_page_ten;
        break;
    case 10:
        resId = R.layout.activity_page_eleven;
        break;
    case 11:
        resId = R.layout.activity_page_twelve;
        break;
    case 12:
        resId = R.layout.activity_page_thirteen;
        break;
    case 13:
        resId = R.layout.activity_page_fourteen;
        break;
    case 14:
        resId = R.layout.activity_page_fifteen;

        View view3 = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        LinearLayout layout3 = (LinearLayout) view3
                .findViewById(R.id.lineartools);
        Button toolsButton = (Button) layout3
                .findViewById(R.id.addToolsQuestionsButton);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view3, 0);

        toolsButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.d("clicked", "clclcl");
                LessonActivity.
                importQuestions("lessonthreetoolsquestions");
                // LessonActivity.clicked = true;
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yay",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        return view3;

    }
    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

    return view;

}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2)
{
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState()
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}
```

}

Thank you again. Here is my added code!

Comment: i think you have to set adapter as per your requirement, suppose if user select lesson first then adapter will configure with only two page data and again set  myPager.setAdapter(adapter); , if user select lesson second then adapter will configure with 3-9 page data and again set myPager.setAdapter(adapter);.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.Okay, I will try this and report back.

Comment: Okay, I tried to do that and was confused on what methods to use. I don't have much experience with page viewer. As of now it goes to the right page to start off if I have: myPager.setCurrentItem(2); Why is there no setEndingItem? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a listener for page changes and then force the user to a certain page if they get outside of your range.  Using `onPageSelected()` you could detect the out of bounds page and then force the user to the previous page.
Here's the listener: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html

I think a better solution though would be to only add certain pages to your ViewPager depending on what lesson the user chooses.  If you have a main Activity with the buttons to select the lessons, then when clicked they could start different Activities that have the ViewPagers filled with the pages you want.  So it would look like:

```
MainActivity
- Button1
    -Activity with ViewPager for pages 1-2
- Button2
    -Activity with ViewPager for pages 3-9
- Button3
    -Activity with ViewPager for pages 10-15
```

I think the structuring it like this is better organized.

Comment: I was able to finally get everything working with your suggestions. Thank you again!